# json_query in ansible to find the key value and print the other key in the json object

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, json-query

this is the raw data I want to search this using json_query in ansible with keyvalue=65060 and print the corresponding Neighbor, can anyone please help.

so far I got this:

```
   - name: data manipulate
      debug: msg="{{ msnjson | json_query(msnquery) }}"
      vars:
        msnquery: "[*].AS"
```

but this just displays all AS keys but I'm looking for exactly the key with value 65060 and corresponding Neighbor Key.

```
[
  {
    "AS": "65060",
    "InQ": "0",
    "MsgRcvd": "258259",
    "MsgSent": "120410",
    "Neighbor": "99.99.99.5",
    "OutQ": "0",
    "Spk": "0",
    "StPfxRcd": "1",
    "TblVer": "2241",
    "UpDown": "2w0d"
  },
  {
    "AS": "64600",
    "InQ": "0",
    "MsgRcvd": "281828",
    "MsgSent": "120498",
    "Neighbor": "192.168.100.1",
    "OutQ": "0",
    "Spk": "0",
    "StPfxRcd": "33",
    "TblVer": "2241",
    "UpDown": "12w5d"
  },
  {
    "AS": "64600",
    "InQ": "0",
    "MsgRcvd": "281867",
    "MsgSent": "120498",
    "Neighbor": "192.168.100.2",
    "OutQ": "0",
    "Spk": "0",
    "StPfxRcd": "33",
    "TblVer": "2241",
    "UpDown": "12w5d"
  },
  {
    "AS": "64600",
    "InQ": "0",
    "MsgRcvd": "258516",
    "MsgSent": "120499",
    "Neighbor": "192.168.100.4",
    "OutQ": "0",
    "Spk": "0",
    "StPfxRcd": "19",
    "TblVer": "2241",
    "UpDown": "5w6d"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```yaml
    - name: data manipulate
      debug: msg="{{ msnjson | json_query(msnquery) }}"
      vars:
        msnquery: "[?AS=='65060'].Neighbor"
```

---

**Update**

There are multiple items with the same value of *AS*. It might be practical to create a dictionary if you have to search *Neighbor* by *AS* repeatedly. For example,

```yaml
  AS_Neighbors: "{{ [msnjson|json_query(msnquery), []]|
                    community.general.lists_mergeby('AS', list_merge='append')|
                    items2dict(key_name='AS', value_name='Neighbor') }}"
  msnquery: "[].{AS: AS, Neighbor: [Neighbor]}"
```

gives

```yaml
  AS_Neighbors:
    '64600':
    - 192.168.100.1
    - 192.168.100.2
    - 192.168.100.4
    '65060':
    - 99.99.99.5
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    AS_Neighbors: "{{ [msnjson|json_query(msnquery), []]|
                      community.general.lists_mergeby('AS', list_merge='append')|
                      items2dict(key_name='AS', value_name='Neighbor') }}"
    msnquery: "[].{AS: AS, Neighbor: [Neighbor]}"

    msnjson:
      - AS: '65060'
        InQ: '0'
        MsgRcvd: '258259'
        MsgSent: '120410'
        Neighbor: 99.99.99.5
        OutQ: '0'
        Spk: '0'
        StPfxRcd: '1'
        TblVer: '2241'
        UpDown: 2w0d
      - AS: '64600'
        InQ: '0'
        MsgRcvd: '281828'
        MsgSent: '120498'
        Neighbor: 192.168.100.1
        OutQ: '0'
        Spk: '0'
        StPfxRcd: '33'
        TblVer: '2241'
        UpDown: 12w5d
      - AS: '64600'
        InQ: '0'
        MsgRcvd: '281867'
        MsgSent: '120498'
        Neighbor: 192.168.100.2
        OutQ: '0'
        Spk: '0'
        StPfxRcd: '33'
        TblVer: '2241'
        UpDown: 12w5d
      - AS: '64600'
        InQ: '0'
        MsgRcvd: '258516'
        MsgSent: '120499'
        Neighbor: 192.168.100.4
        OutQ: '0'
        Spk: '0'
        StPfxRcd: '19'
        TblVer: '2241'
        UpDown: 5w6d

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: AS_Neighbors
```

Comment: awesome, it worked.
I was thinking first we need to eliminate the list and then match the key. thank you very much, appreciated!